# C Programming: Order Details doesn't display properly

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char Meal, MealType, Drinks, DrinksType;
    int Amount, Quantity;

    printf("Meal: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%c", &Meal);

    switch (Meal) {
    case 'A':
        Meal = ("Chicken & Spaghetti");
        break;
    case 'B':
        Meal = ("Hamburger & Fries");
        break;
    case 'C':
        Meal = ("Cheese Burger");
        break;
    case 'D':
        Meal = ("Pizza");
        break;

    }

    printf("Drinks: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%c %c", &Drinks);

    switch (Drinks) {
    case 'S':
        Drinks = ("Small Drinks");
        break;
    case 'M':
        Drinks = ("Medium Drinks");
        break;
    case 'L':
        Drinks = ("Large Drinks");
        break;
    }
    printf("Quantity: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%i", &Quantity);

    printf("Order Details: %c and %c ", Meal, Drinks);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is displayed as:

```
Meal: B
Drinks: S
Quantity: 2
Order Details: ‚ and
```

I'm trying to make the Order details display properly, thank you for your help!

Comment: `scanf("%c %c", &Drinks);` - you have two format specifiers, but only one destination

Comment: What do you mean by "properly"? How do you expect the output to look?

Comment: Also `Drinks = ("Small Drinks");` etc isn't right when you have `char Drinks`.

Comment: and you might want a space before the `%c` like this `scanf(" %c", &Drinks);`

Comment: I expected the output to look as "Hamburger & Fries and Small Drinks".

Comment: It appears you misunderstand the `char` type. `char` can hold *one character*. You need to use `char` arrays to hold strings or `char*` to point at strings.

Comment: has your compiler showed you any of [these warnings?](https://godbolt.org/z/n8bMMax1z) It should.

Comment: You can use another variable, such as `char *MealDescrip` and then `MealDescrip = "Hamburger & Fries";` and then `%s` in the `printf` output. Note that you didn't use `MealType` but overwrote `Meal` so a careful review of the code is needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help everyone, I more or less understand what needs to be fixed. Sorry for the vague responses as I am a beginner at C programming.